# How to match whole word in a string

Tags: python

I would like to pickup whole words in a string that separated by space, comma or period.

```
text = 'OTC GLUCOSAM-CHOND-MSM1-C-MANG-BOR test, dosage uncertain'
p = r"(?i)\b([A-Za-z]+[\s*|\,|\.]+)\b"    
for m in regex.finditer(p, str(text)):
    print (m.group())
```

I expect to get: 
OTC 
GLUCOSAM-CHOND-MSM1-C-MANG-BOR 
test 
dosage 
uncertain

but what I got: 
OTC 
BOR 
test, 
dosage

Comment: try https://regex101.com/

Comment: Your regex isn't allowing for the hyphens.

Comment: I wonder if split would work better for you given you know exactly what you want to split on: `re.split(r'[\s+,.]+', text)`

Comment: @MarkMeyer I suggest writing that up as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of the words that you want, you can use the `findall()` function of the `re`module. Also, try changing the regular expressions to the one showed below:

```
text = 'OTC GLUCOSAM-CHOND-MSM1-C-MANG-BOR test, dosage uncertain'
result = re.findall('[\w]+[-?[\w]+]*', text)

print(result)
# outputs: ['OTC', 'GLUCOSAM-CHOND-MSM1-C-MANG-BOR', 'test', 'dosage', 'uncertain']
```

Answer (score 1):

import re

text = 'OTC GLUCOSAM-CHOND-MSM1-C-MANG-BOR test, dosage uncertain'

p = r"[a-zA-Z-\d]*"

for m in re.finditer(p, str(text)):

```
if len(m.group().strip()) > 0:
  print(m.group())
```